# .exe File becomes corrupted when downloaded from server

Tags: php, file-upload, download

Firstly:  I'm a lowly web designer who knows just enough PHP to be dangerous and just enough about server administration to be, well, nothing.  I probably won't understand you unless you're very clear!

The setup:  I've set up a website where the client uploads files to a specific directory, and those files are made available, through php, for download by users.  The files are generally executable files over 50MB.  The client does not want them zipped, as they feel their users aren't savvy enough to unzip them. I'm using the php below to force a download dialogue box and hide the directory where the files are located.

It's Linux server, if that makes a difference.

The problem:  There is a certain file that becomes corrupt after the user tries to download it. It is an executable file, but when it's clicked on, a blank DOS window opens up.  The original file, prior to download opens perfectly.  There are several other similar files that go through the same exact download procedure, and all of those work just fine.

Things I've tried: I've tried uploading the file zipped, then unzipping it on the server to make sure it wasn't becoming corrupt during upload, and no luck.
<strike>I've also compared the binary code of the original file to the downloaded file that doesn't work, and they're exactly the same (so the php isn't accidentally inserting anything extra into the file).</strike>

Could it be an issue with the headers in my downloadFile function? I really am not sure how to troubleshoot this one…

This is the download php, if it's relevant ($filenamereplace is defined elsewhere):

```
downloadFile("../DIRECTORY/files/$filenamereplace","$filenamereplace");

function downloadFile($file,$filename){    
    if(file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        @ flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
}
```

**ETA Additonal Info:**
- Tests for working/non-working files have been done on the same machine
- If it makes any difference, the original file has a custom icon.  After download, the file has a generic blank document icon.

**Additonal Info: I THINK THIS ONE'S IMPORTANT!**
I just tried downloading the file directly (to bypass the download link that triggers the download function above).  If I download the file by just going to its url and downloading it that way, the downloaded file WORKS.  So I'm thinking it must have something to do with the download function.  But what??

**3/17 MAJOR CORRECTION —AND RESOLVED—**
So I woke up this morning and it dawned on me that maybe I was comparing the files wrong. (I had re-saved them as binary text, and *then* compared them.  I didn't realize the comparison program would take and compare actual exe files).  This morning I tried comparing the actual exe files and there **is** a difference. There was one line of php code that was being injected into the first line of the file.  I adjusted the php, and the problem was fixed.  (It was from the if/else statement that defined teh $filenamereplace variable in the code I'd cited).  Thanks again for all your help, and sorry for misleading you in insisting that the files' contents were identical!

Comment: I don't think you have to flush headers. some hex editors can compare files

Comment: Should I remove that "@ flush();" line, then?  Could the flushing of the headers be what's causing the problem, or are you just saying that it's not necessary.  (I honestly don't know what it actually does…)

Comment: One bit of clarification - can you open the original file (pre upload) on the same machine that the downloaded version is failing on?  Just to make sure to remove any machine specific issues?  If the bits are the same and other exes download fine, seems to me you need to start looking at environmental (e.g. machine) configuration issues?

Comment: Eric, good question.  Yes.  The original file will open perfectly, and when I download the file from the server on the same machine, the downloaded file does not open.

Comment: Also, I don't know if it makes a difference, as I'm used to working in a Mac platform, but I noticed that, though the file is named "file.exe", the dowloaded file, as it shows on the desktop is only called "file".  Is that normal for the file extension to be hidden?  I actually tried adding .exe back to the file name after download, just to give it a shot, but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Are you downloading the file onto a network share or anything like that?

Comment: Yes, in a default windows installation file extensions are hidden (first thing to change :P)

Comment: Earlz, nope.  Straight onto the desktop.  And several of the people at the client's company have tried with the same results.

PS.  You guys rock!  I love all the questions and answers coming in.  I'm really impressed with this place!

Comment: I just discovered something that may be very important. Please see my "ETAA" edit a the end of the main post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I've also compared the binary code of the original file to the downloaded file that doesn't work, and their exactly the same (so the php isn't accidentally inserting anything extra into the file)."

If that's really true, then the problem must be in how the exe is started after it has been downloaded. It should certainly not be a problem with your PHP code.

Comment: Can you tell me more about what you mean by "how the exe is started after it has been downloaded"?  Do I have any control over this from the website?  Thanks!

Comment: After the exe is downloaded it must be started. By "how" I mean does the browser start it, does the user click it in explorer, etc. You have no control over that.
That's a weird place for a problem though, so are you 10000% sure the files are binary identical?

Comment: The file is meant to be double clicked by the user to start it.  It's an install file, and the install process should begin when it's clicked.  Instead, a blank DOS window is coming up.

Comment: Have you used a binary diff application to make sure they are **exactly** the same? If so, try moving the application(from where you upload) to where you download it to test that it isn't some weird directory issue

Comment: Earlz.  Yes, I used the KDiff3 app to compare the two files and it found no differences, not a one.  I'm clear on your suggestion, though.  The file is uploaded via ftp to the same directory that it is downloaded from.

Comment: Earlz meant that you should try running the downloaded file from the same directory that the originally uploaded one is in (on your computer, not the server). If the files are binary equal, you can completely exclude the server and site from the list of where to search for the cause.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps they were corrupted on upload. This can happen if you transfer them via FTP in ASCII mode instead of BINARY.

Comment: "Things I've tried: I've tried uploading the file zipped, then unzipping it on the server to make sure it wasn't becoming corrupt during upload, and no luck."

Comment: That was my first thought, actually. That's why I tried uploading it to the server first as a zipped file, then unzipping it once it was uploaded.  Wouldn't that have avoided any corruption issues for the actual exe file on upload? 

(Hah. plod beat me to it)